# First order non linear ODE with non-constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve numerically and ODE of the form, $$ A(x) + B(x)\dot{x} + C(x)\dot{x}^2 = 0.$$

I've tried many things such as but did not come up with a satisfying solution, anybody got an  idea of a method to solve this one ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks @josé-carlos-santos, but if you need more information regarding my question, please ask me, I don't see what's missing here.

Comment: @MaximeL. This is a broad topic. What numerical methods do you already know to solve ODE? Please update your question with that. You could at least solve the equation in terms of $ \dot x$ and then use known numerical methods. This is also depending a lot on what the maps $A,B,C$ are.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand the methods I know can change the answer, but I know Euler and RK methods. 

I don't see what you mean by solving the equation in terms of $\dot{x}$. Do you have some literature to suggest for the  dependency of the solution with $A,B$ and $C$ ?

Comment: "Solving the equation in terms of x'" (I would say "solving the equation FOR x') means, I believe, getting x'= -(C(x)x^2+ A(x))/B(x).

Comment: Indeed, but I am probably wrong, but,  that would work with $C(x) x^2$ in my case I have $C(x)\dot{x}^2$ leading to $\dot{x} =-(C(x)\dot{x}^2+ A(x))/B(x).$ I don't see any simplification from the latter.

Comment: Guess I'll solve $$\dot{x} = \frac{-B \pm \sqrt{B^2  - 4AC}}{2A}~.$$

Comment: Note that you need to chose the solution of the quadratic equation that is closest to the solution/derivative in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

$$ A(x) + B(x)\dot{x} + C(x)\dot{x}^2 = 0.$$
Are you sure about what you wrote? Let try to clearfy.

The variable of differentiation is missing in the equation. Suppose that the variable be $t$. Thus $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$.

$$ A(x(t)) + B(x(t))\frac{dx}{dt} + C(x(t))\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2 = 0.\qquad\text{Is it OK ?}$$

If YES ,
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{2C(x)}\left(-B(x)\pm \sqrt{\big(B(x)\big)^2-4C(x)A(x)}\right)$$
$$dt=\frac{2C(x)}{-B(x)\pm \sqrt{\big(B(x)\big)^2-4C(x)A(x)}}dx$$
$$t=\int \frac{2C(x)}{-B(x)\pm \sqrt{\big(B(x)\big)^2-4C(x)A(x)}}dx+\text{constant}$$
Since $A(x) , B(x) , C(x)$ are given (known) functions, then
$$f(x)=\frac{2C(x)}{-B(x)\pm \sqrt{\big(B(x)\big)^2-4C(x)A(x)}} \quad\text{is a known function}.$$
A first problem is to integrate $f(x)$:
$$t=\int f(x)dx+\text{constant}$$
If the integration is possible we find the function $F(x)$ which is antiderivative of $f(x)$.
$$t=F(x)+\text{constant}$$
A second problem is to find the inverse function of $F$, say $F^{-1}$. Don't confuse with $\frac{1}{F}$.

If it is possible the solution of the problem is :

$$x(t)=F^{-1}\big(t-\text{constant}\big)$$

Of course one cannot say if the integration and the inversion are analytically possible without knowing what kind of functions $A(x),B(x),C(x)$ are.